# LaTeX not breaking a line containing multiple tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

I think the example below best illustrates the issue I'm having. The line only appears to be broken, when the new `tikzpicture` would completely fall outside of the available space. How can I make LaTeX automatically insert a line break after the second `tikzpicture`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=19cm,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\rect}{ %
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (9,5.2);
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (9,5.2);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
  \rect
  \rect
  \rect
  \rect
\end{document}
```

This code results in the following document:
[image: An example showing the problem]

Comment: use `\raggedright` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line breaking treats a tikzpicture just like a big letter, so you can use `\raggedright` here.